# Angular pagination, stop paging

Tags: angularjs, pagination, paging

Hi I have a problem with retention, Warts pages in pagination. I mean to block pagination 1 and that did not show up to 0. The need to find a condition?

```
$scope.setPage = function (index) {
        $scope.items.paging.offset = index;
        console.log(index);
    };
```

[all projekt in Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/GBavRQ7rXf1OQGEkOpsf)

Answer (score 0):

## paginator.html

The following code:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li ng-repeat="index in [getSelectedPage() - 1 , getSelectedPage(), getSelectedPage() + 1]"
        ng-click = "setPage(index)">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">{{ index + 1  }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

could be redesign to something like:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li ng-repeat="index in getPaginationButtons()"
        ng-click = "setPage(index)">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">{{ index + 1  }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

## paginator.js

The following code could be added:

```
// but IMHO it's not very good to hardcode 3 buttons
// and not to check a number of available pages
$scope.getPaginationButtons = function () {
    var buttons = [];

    // TODO: fix offset or set it to 0
    // if $scope.items.paging.offset is out of valid range
    // for example, someone removes all items
    // from another tab or window or browser
    // and then you click on the page offset
    // which is not present

    if ($scope.items.paging.offset > 0) {
      buttons.push($scope.items.paging.offset - 1);
    }

    buttons.push($scope.items.paging.offset);

    // TODO: do the following only if the next page is present
    buttons.push($scope.items.paging.offset + 1);

    return buttons;
};
```

Comment: Ok thanks:) but I do not know how to do to make it appear sufficient amount buttonów depending on items. I calculated how much should be bars but I do not know how to display them  ->  https://plnkr.co/edit/N8HZ6qCtsj0fF4YMULFW

Comment: Current logic of generateButtons() differs from the suggested one (i.e. differs from getPaginationButtons()): generateButtons() does not depend on offset now, but suggested getPaginationButtons() depends on offset. Please fix this (take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/36828555/1409749)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the following part could be improved in [suggested code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36720422/1409749):

```
if ($scope.items.paging.offset > 0) {
  buttons.push($scope.items.paging.offset - 1);
}

buttons.push($scope.items.paging.offset);

// TODO: do the following only if the next page is present
buttons.push($scope.items.paging.offset + 1);
```

and should be replaced by something like:

```
// if not a first page then add a number of previous one
if ($scope.offset > 0) {
  buttons.push($scope.offset / $scope.limit - 1);
}

buttons.push($scope.offset / $scope.limit);

// if there are more pages then show button of the next one
if (($scope.offset + $scope.limit) < $scope.total) {
  buttons.push($scope.offset / $scope.limit + 1);
}
```

And the following code from your latest plunker example (i.e. from https://plnkr.co/edit/N8HZ6qCtsj0fF4YMULFW):

```
    function getPageCount() {
        return Math.ceil($scope.total / $scope.limit);
    }
```

should be deprecated/removed.

And the following page **index** to **offset** calculation should be used IMHO:

```
    $scope.setPage = function (index) {
        $scope.offset = index * $scope.limit;
    };
```